# How to display only 5 cells in CollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

i want to show only 5 posts from my Wordpress Website into CollectionView in my Swift app. i am very new to Swift. i have set this as url

```
https://www.sikhnama.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?categories=4&per_page=5
```

and this get only 5 posts from Wordpress but in collectionView after 5 posts it repeats the posts, but i want after 5 cells there should not be any more cell and post.
this is my code ..

```
 func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return newsData.count + (newsData.count/4)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
     if (indexPath.item % 4 == 3){
        
        let adcell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "adcell", for: indexPath) as! RelatedViewCell
         
        
       
         adcell.banner.adUnitID = bannerAd
         adcell.banner.rootViewController = self
         adcell.banner.load(GADRequest())
         adcell.banner.delegate = self
        
       return adcell
        
    }
    
    else{
        
       
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "postcell", for: indexPath) as! RelatedViewCell
        
        
        
        cell.setup(with: newsData[indexPath.row-(indexPath.row/4)])
        return cell
    }
}
```

i have tried this also

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return 5
}
```

then i get error on this line that "Index out of Range"

```
 cell.setup(with: newsData[indexPath.row-(indexPath.row/4)])
```

also tried

```
cell.setup(with: newsData[indexPath.row])
```

but not works,, help please

Comment: You're returning **2 sections** ... but neither your `numberOfItemsInSection` nor `cellForItemAt` accounts for that. So, you're getting the same data in each section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments...

With this code:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 2
}
```

You are saying the collection view has two sections.

But, in neither `numberOfItemsInSection` nor `cellForItemAt` are you accounting for multiple sections.

So, you are duplicating the same cells in each section.

Unless you really have 2 sections, you should return `1` for `numberOfSections`

Answer (score -1):

The numbersOfItemsInSection func is what you will set to show only 5. But if you are grabbing data from an api there might not be 5 leaving you with a "Index out of Range" error.

What I would do:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
if newsData.count + (newsData.count/4) > 5 {
return 5
} else {
 return newsData.count + (newsData.count/4)
 }     
}
```

This will check the data coming back and if greater than 5 only show 5 if it's less than 5 it will show that amount.